# Jquery Coinslider goto exact frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

i am trying to make my coinslider go to an exact frame by pressing another button somewhere in my website.

I've looked at the code many time and couldn't figure it out, so the only thing i could think of having it to work is doing so :

```
$("#cs-button-coinslider-3").trigger('click');
```

But as expected, this does not fix my problem..

Any help on this would be really nice ! Thanks

For those who requested the coinslider "Thumbnails click", i do belive its on line 241 from this link https://github.com/kopipejst/coin-slider/blob/master/coin-slider.js

Finally i just had put the code in the wrong place, the slideshow would not accept it unless its "shown on the page" and not hidden with CSS - display:none

Can use the code shown up there if you ever need to do a click even to bring the slider to where you need it

Comment: can you please post your html code? do you have an on click event defined for #cs-button-coinslider-3? e.g. $("#cs-button-coinslider-3").on("click", function(){ /* do something */});

Comment: try this ... $("#cs-next-coinslider-3").trigger("click");

Comment: I can't use the Next button since i do hide them first, and second i want to go to a specefic frame, not the next one.. thanks though for the tip ! .. Also the click event is already handled by the Coinslider.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code down here will work for the Button you want to click on the coinslider. (It will automatically generate X amount of #cs-button-nameofyourslider-X for the amount of slides you want it to have)

```
 $('#cs-button-bottleslides-1').click();
```